# the following code is working fine in VS 2010 but giving error in VS2008,WHY? "ClassOne" is a class with Properties IDX,NAME,MOBILENUMBER

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, using

```
Dim obj As New List(Of ClassOne)() From { _
 New ClassOne() With { _
   Key .IDX = 1206, _
   Key .NAME = "Krishna Reddy", _
   Key .MOBLIENUMBER = 9494494704L _
   }, _
    New ClassOne() With { _
     Key .IDX = 1242, _
     Key .NAME = "Swarupa", _
     Key .MOBLIENUMBER = 9441524535L _
     }, _
    New ClassOne() With { _
     Key .IDX = 1236, _
     Key .NAME = "Naga Raj", _
     Key .MOBLIENUMBER = 9866939656L _
    }, _
    New ClassOne() With { _
     Key .IDX = 1219, _
     Key .NAME = "Devika", _
     Key .MOBLIENUMBER = 9885735365L _
   } _
  }

  test.DataSource = obj    //here "test" is dropdownlist id
  test.DataTextField = "NAME"
  test.DataValueField = "IDX"
  test.DataBind()
```

Comment: What error are you getting in VS 2008

Comment: Soo... What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

Collection initializers are new to VS 2010

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/08/new-c-orcas-language-features-automatic-properties-object-initializers-and-collection-initializers.aspx